# Garbage Collection in java

Tags: java

While isolating reference (islands of isolating) a class objects say like the below code

```
public class Island {
    Island i;
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Island i2 = new Island();
        Island i3 = new Island();
        Island i4 = new Island();
        i2.i = i3; // i2 refers to i3
        i3.i = i4; // i3 refers to i4
        i4.i = i2; // i4 refers to i2
        i2 = null;
        i3 = null;
        i4 = null;
        // do complicated, memory intensive stuff
    }
}
```

will these objects be garbage collected? How is that possible then what makes the program run if they are garbage collected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> will these objects be garbage collected?

It is dependent on JVM, we can't surely say that object has been GCed.

Further we can only say that they are ready to GCed.

And It will GCed when there is no live ref to Object exist . so you no need to worry about your program JVM will make sure:)

Answer (score 1):

As for the 'what makes the program run if they are garbage collected', guess that you are missing is that only some Island object instances were GCed, and you start running a program on a static method (main), which does not need any object of its class (Island) to be called.

The thread that the JVM created to execute your 'main' method will keep your application alive as long as it remains executing something (or you create another thread).

Answer (score 0):

In Sun JVM they will be collected.

Answer (score -1):

Yes (unless you've got a **very** old jvm) but only in a major collection. But using recursive classes like this is a bit iffy.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call it "iffy", unless you want to come out saying linked lists are evil.

Comment: And could you explain why only a major collection will collect the objects?  It's not at all obvious.  Seems to me garbage is garbage, and it's all in eden, right?

Comment: -1 - This is wrong on three counts.  1) Even the oldest published Sun JVM had a working garbage collector that could collect a cycle like this. 2) A modern Sun GC can collect the `Island` objects in a minor cycle, since they are unreachable and have never been reachable from a tenured object.  3) There's nothing whatsoever "iffy" about self-referential classes.

Comment: @Stephen C: yes, any JVM with a mark and sweep collector will clean up these objects but since the child objects contain reference to each other, they're not going to picked up by reference counting. As to recursion - what would happen if that method were the constructor?

Comment: see my 1) above.  No "very old" JVM has ever used reference counting.  Re: iffiness - you don't normally try to create a cycle like that in a constructor ... but if there was a real need, you could do it.  But there's nothing iffy about having cycles per se.